# .net 7 maui ios - Can't get push notification while in foreground

Tags: ios, push-notification, maui, .net-7.0

Converting my application from xamarin.forms to .net 7 maui.
In xamarin.forms I was overriding RegisteredForRemoteNotifications and ReceivedRemoteNotification methods.
I can't make a similar code in maui work.
I can see notification when the application is not running. And nothing happens when it is running.

```
public class UserNotificaitonCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public UserNotificaitonCenterDelegate() { }
    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Banner);
        else
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }
}
```

Xamarin.forms:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    private void RegisterForRemoteNotifications()
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications;
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken) {}
    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo) {}
}
```

Maui:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    private void RegisterForRemoteNotifications()
    {           
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificaitonCenterDelegate();
    }
            
    // WORKS! App successfully gets deviceToken
    [Export("application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:")]
    public void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken) {} 
            
    // Doesn't work
    [Export("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:")]
    public void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary notification) {} 
}
```

Also tried to use IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate with no luck:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler) {}

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the registration process. Something like this:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
    UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
    (isSuccess, error) =>
    {
        _logger.LogDebug($"Registration is success: {isSuccess}");

        if (error != null)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"Registration for push notifications error: {error.DebugDescription}");
        }
    });

application.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
```

`application` is UIApplication instance from
`public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)`

Comment: Well, "Registration is success: True". I'm confused with the fact that RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method works, but ReceivedRemoteNotification does not. It's like I'm signing up for the wrong event, but I've already tried everything.

Comment: Do you call completionHandlers in `WillPresentNotification` and `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` ? Or you even don't receive anything there?

```
[Export(...)]
public void WillPresentNotification(...)
{
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Badge);
}

[Export(...)]
public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(...)
{
    completionHandler();
}
```

Comment: both methods never called:
 if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.List | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Banner | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
    else
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the issue and come back with results

Comment: So, I've struggled to make maui work in my environment and as a result I've managed to setup push notifications and successfully tested them for simulator.
Here is repo https://github.com/DimaOrdenov/MauiSamples
How do you send push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code from Maui iOS AppDelegate class
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icGhd.png)